# Swagger.io - array of refs in post method

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

i have a question about how to define an array of refs in swagger using the yaml syntax. I have the following yaml snippet which defines my field:

```
    - name: myfield
      in: formData
      description: 'description'
      required: false
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/definitions/MyRef'
```

The definition is the following:

```
  MyRef:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
      value:
        type: string
        description: the value for the myRef
```

In the preview of my field everything looks fine:

[image: swagger]

But I got the error "Not a valid parameter definition" and in the detailed error I got "Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'".

I can't find anything like this in the documentation. So what's the correct structure or what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's because `formData` may *only* contain primitives or arrays of primitives.  You cannot use a `$ref` as the `items` value.  This will be changed in the next version of the spec (3.0) but it is not supported in the 2.0 tooling because the spec does not allow it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there an alternative what I would like to do? Or do I have to wait until 3.0?

Comment: For now you will have to have an array of strings, and in the string you can un-escape anything that get put in.  Or you can fork & hack the UI but I don't recommend that.  Most people use string arrays as a work around